# Insert into Access returns Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

i try to insert 2 datetimepicker to my database but error in @p1 said object reference not set to an instance of an object 
my code is :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


                Dim date1 As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()
                Dim date2 As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString()
                oleConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\c2cdb.accdb")
                Dim cb As String = "insert into Reqmain(DateOfResive,DateOfIssue,UnitID,DeviseType,expectedCrush,Attachments,WorkerID) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", date1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", date2)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",convert.ToInt32(ComUnits.ValueMember))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", tbDeviseType.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", tbExpCrush.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", tbattach.Text)
                md.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7",convert.ToInt32(comWorker.ValueMember))
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb)
                cmd.Connection = oleConn
                oleConn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                oleConn.Close()
          End Sub
```

Comment: At which line are you getting this error ? did you checked that all the variables that are used in the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue really contain a value (and not null or empty) ? are you succesfully stablishing a connection with the database ?

Comment: the exception raised on    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", date1) and i checked that no parameter is null

Comment: The date value is the same in MS Acces ?

Comment: @Orlando Herrera yes it is the same

Comment: Does VB.Net allow you to do `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` *before* you do `cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb)`?  I don't know VB.Net, but that looks suspicious to me.  Seems like you should create the `cmd` object first and then add the parameter values.

Comment: Place that as an answer instead @HansUp. I do belive you are correct.

Comment: thank you i change the CMD to  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cb, oleConn) and i put it before parameters and now problem in mismatch datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small code is working for me:

```
Try
        Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=yourDB.accdb;")
        Dim cb As String = "insert into Table1 (Date1, Sample1) VALUES (@p1, @p2)"
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = cb
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Me.TextBox1.Text)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Err.Description)
End Try
```